# Windows 8.1 Allow incoming VPN connection

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1

I was able to allow an incoming VPN connection in Windows 8. Since updating to 8.1, I can't find any way of doing so.

As an example, [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/) used to work, but now, none of the things are where they say they are.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which part is no longer present/doesn't work?

Comment: Any of it. The network connections dialog is different and no longer has a menu bar for example. If it helps, I'd just like a set of steps to enable an incoming connection on Windows 8.1. I've been googling around and there seems there was some sort of change, but no answers yet :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right solved it. And Microsoft, if you're reading this I am not impressed.

Go to "Network and Internet" from Control panel, then "Network and sharing center".

Click "Change adapter settings".

The next step is the moronic one.

Press the **Alt** key. You may have to press it twice, it doesn't always do what says which is to **MAKE THE MENU BAR APPEAR**. The menu bar will also disappear if you switch away from the window, if for example you are writing these instructions in a separate browser window.

From the menu bar you can select "New incoming connection" from the file menu, and from that point you can follow the tutorial above.

Comment: Wow. You, sir, officially rock.

Comment: in addition to make menu bar appear. :
if you see the organise button:
click and select Layout. activate menu or just press ALT + F (both will disable the moronic step)

Comment: Absolutely amazing answer, worth of a thousand upvotes.